# Remove an element from the result of an Active Record query

Tags: arrays, activerecord, sqlite, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am new to Rails and I am having a problem with the results of an Active Record query.

I have a Class method (this_week ) that returns 3 recipe records from my database.  I would like to delete one of the returned records from the query (*not* the database) while maintaining the other 2 records.

When I am in my View for the Index page, and try to delete one of the records that is returned I get the following error: “Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/Lomo%20saltado”

How can I delete *this part* of the returned query?

Any help that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

**Model**

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base 

  belongs_to :recipe 
  belongs_to :recipe_collection 

  def self.this_week 
    @line_items =  LineItem.order("RANDOM()").limit(3) 
    @line_items.map{ |line_item| line_item.recipe.title }  
  end 

end
```

**View**

```
<%= @line_items.this_week[0] %>  <%=link_to 'Remove', @line_items.this_week.delete_at(0) %> <br>
```

**Controller**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController 
  include UserRecipe #Error: Couldn't find recipe with id / off: undefined meth: Set_rec_collect 
  before_action :set_recipe_collection, only: [:create] 
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :last_eaten] 

  def index 
    @line_items = LineItem.where(nil) 
    @line_items = LineItem.all 
    @line_items.this_week 

   end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :line_items
  resources :recipe_collections
  devise_for :users
  resources :recipes
  root "recipes#index"
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solutions:
in your view:

```
<%=link_to 'Remove', @line_items(remove_item: params[:remove_item].to_i + 1) %>
```

in your controller:

```
@line_items = LineItem.all
@line_items = @line_items.limit(LineItem.count - params[:remove_item].to_i) if params[:remove_item].present?
```

Comment: After adding the above code, I got the error: "/home/gregb/workspace/Sandbox/recipe_box/app/views/line_items/index.html.erb:49: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' ...(link_to 'Remove', @line_items(remove_item: params[:remove_i... ... ^  

/home/gregb/workspace/Sandbox/recipe_box/app/views/line_items/index.html.erb:49: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ...arams[:remove_item].to_i + 1) );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... ^ "